# generic class for static variables

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to write more generic class for below code so the type and static variables that define in EvenTypes can be changed by the end developer and give them options to add or remove static variables in EventType.

I'm also think of having generic enum for event type as below.

```
public interface EventType<T extends Enum<T>>
{
    String name();

    String getFriendlyName();

    Class<T> getDeclaringClass();

    T getRaw();

    public String getFullClassName();
}
```

### Original Code

```
    public class Event implements Serializable
    {

        private String eventId;
        private String eventType;
            .....

}

public class EventTypes
{// below static variables can be changed by the developer based on requirements
    public static final String DO_FILE_CONVERSION = "100";
    public static final String DO_REMOVE_FILE = "101";
    public static final String DO_COPY_FILE = "102";
    .....

    }


public class EventProcessorFactory
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public IEventProcessor createProcessor(EventType eventType)
                throws EventException
        {
            String eventProcessorClassName = (getEvenClassName  based on type from properties files);
            Class eventProcessorClazz = Class.forName(eventProcessorClassName);
return (IEventProcessor) eventProcessorClazz.newInstance();
            }
    }

properties.file
----
100=FileConversion.class
101=FileRemove.class
102= FileCopy.class
```

Comment: Why? What's the gain here? You're loosing type safety, you add complexity, errors are easy to make, and to change the properties file you need to add code anyway. Why??

Comment: The reason is those static variables supposed to be added by the end developer. I want to provide only interface

Comment: Why don't you make `EventTypes` an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? (<= click for tutorial). Note that enums can have methods and member variables, and can also implement an interface - you could have a `public enum EventTypes implements EventType`.

Answer (score 0):

Make Event an interface and extend it from Serializable.

Then use an enum to implement that Event interface. Example:

```
public interface Event extends Serializable {
     // Throw in your methods here
}

public enum MyEvents implements Event {
    DO_FILE_CONVERSION, DO_REMOVE_FILE, DO_COPY_FILE;
    // Implement methods
}
```

This way you have your interface (namely whatever you want Event capable of doing) seperated from the implementation (which Events exist and the implementation of them).